# Is there any way to programme the main signer?

Tags: gnosis-safe, multisignature

I want to create, for example, a safe for 4 users. The transaction must have 3 signatures. One of us is the main investor and has the best knowledge. Is it possible to programme the signature so that he is always sure to be among the three signatories? Otherwise the three without him might do something stupid.

Comment: An out-of-the-box solution is to give the founder 2 addresses, so the safe has 5 total addresses, and to set the threshold signatures to 4.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is indeed possible to implement such a condition in a multisignature wallet contract.

One way of doing this could be to always require the signature from the main investor for every transaction and then any two other signatures from the remaining three investors.

Here's a simple example using OpenZeppelin's `multisigwallet` as a base:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.2;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol";

contract MultiSigWallet is AccessControl {
    bytes32 public constant MAIN_INVESTOR_ROLE = keccak256("MAIN_INVESTOR_ROLE");
    uint256 private _transactionIdCounter = 0;
    uint256 private _requiredSignatures = 3; 

    struct Transaction {
        address destination;
        uint256 value;
        bool executed;
        uint256 confirmations;
    }

    mapping (uint256 => Transaction) private _transactions;
    mapping (uint256 => mapping (address => bool)) private _confirmations;

    constructor(address[] memory investors, address mainInvestor) public {
        _setupRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, _msgSender());

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < investors.length; ++i) {
            grantRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, investors[i]);
        }
        
        grantRole(MAIN_INVESTOR_ROLE, mainInvestor);
    }

    function submitTransaction(address destination, uint256 value)
        public
        onlyRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE)
        returns (uint256 transactionId)
    {
        transactionId = _transactionIdCounter++;
        _transactions[transactionId] = Transaction({
            destination: destination,
            value: value,
            executed: false,
            confirmations: 0
        });

        return transactionId;
    }

    function confirmTransaction(uint256 transactionId)
        public
        onlyRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE)
    {
        require(_transactions[transactionId].executed == false, 'Transaction already executed');
        require(_confirmations[transactionId][_msgSender()] == false, 'You have already confirmed this transaction');

        _confirmations[transactionId][_msgSender()] = true;
        _transactions[transactionId].confirmations += 1;
        
        if(hasRole(MAIN_INVESTOR_ROLE, _msgSender())) {
            executeTransaction(transactionId);
        } else {
            require(_transactions[transactionId].confirmations >= _requiredSignatures-1, 'Not enough confirmations yet.');
        }
    }

    function executeTransaction(uint256 transactionId) public onlyRole(MAIN_INVESTOR_ROLE) {
        require(_transactions[transactionId].executed == false, 'Transaction already executed');
        require(_transactions[transactionId].confirmations >= _requiredSignatures-1, 'Not enough confirmations yet.');

        _transactions[transactionId].executed = true;
        (bool success, ) = _transactions[transactionId].destination.call{value: _transactions[transactionId].value}("");
        
        require(success, 'Execution failed.');        
    }
}
```

In the contract above, a transaction is submitted by users with role `DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE`. If it's confirmed by the main investor, it gets executed straight away. If it's confirmed by the other investors, it will not get executed unless there are at least two confirmations and the main investor confirms it.

Please adapt this to suit your needs and ensure to thoroughly test it before using it on mainnet!

Lastly, remember that this code should be considered as an example and should be revised and tested before any production-level usage. Always consider possible attack vectors and "worst-case" scenarios when designing smart contracts.